# How do I take the integral of complex power function with a non-integral power?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I cannot find any references talking about how to do this, and I cannot figure it out. Suppose we have

$\int_\Gamma z^{a/b} dz$,

where $z \in \mathbb{C}$ and $\Gamma$ is some contour which has an endpoint on the negative real axis.

I know that we need to convert $z^{a/b}$ to $e^{a/b \ \text{Log}(z)}$, but then I don't know what to do. Any help would be appreciated.

(I am aware there is a question asked with an almost identical title, but it is not helpful and has no answer.)

Comment: As long as the integrand has a simple antiderivative $z\mapsto F(z)$ (multivalued or not), and the contour is not too pathological (say, it avoids the singularities of $F$, does not cross branch cuts of $F$ infinitely often, etc.), you can go the "fundamental theorem of calculus" way. I.e., split the contour into pieces which don't cross branch cuts of $F$, and sum $F(z_2^-)-F(z_1^+)$ for each piece $z_1\to z_2$. The main problem with these integrals is that you have no longer the full freedom to deform the contour at will.

Comment: What about having an endpoint along the branchcut? I'm also not understanding how to integrate $e^{a/b\text{Log}(z)}$. I don't know what the antiderivative of that is, since it's complex. Especially when the idea of branchcut comes in. @metamorphy

Comment: The "endpoint on a branchcut" case is *covered* by my comment above. Just take the appropriate limits. As for the rest... forget your "$e^{a/b\ldots}$". An antiderivative of $z^\alpha$ for $\alpha\neq-1$ is $z^{\alpha+1}/(\alpha+1)$ with the same branch cuts that are assigned to $z^\alpha$ (which pertains to the case of non-integer $\alpha$, of course). Thus the FTC approach is viable here. The case of $\alpha=-1$ (when the integrand has no branch cuts but any antiderivative has) is famous - you get the log (and stuff like $2\pi i$ and Cauchy integral formula).

Comment: Thank you so much! If you put that in an answer I'll accept it. @metamorphy

Comment: As for an answer... I'll let someone to get it in a more complete manner. I think I didn't cover all the details.